# Cython - gil related issues

Tags: python, cython

I have the following code, that I am trying to parallelize. The description is given below

```
# cython: boundscheck=False
# cython: wraparound=False
# cython: cdivision=True

cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as cnp
from numpy cimport ndarray as ar

# define a function pointer
ctypedef void (*vector_ptr)(double[:], double, double[:])

cdef void sma_vec(double[:] x, double m, double[:] y) nogil:
    cdef:
        int n
        int mi = int(m)
        Py_ssize_t i, j
    n = x.shape[0]
    for i in range(mi-1, n):
        for j in range(i-mi+1, i+1):
            if j == i-mi+1:
                y[i] = x[j]
            else:
                y[i] += x[j]
        y[i] /= m

cdef void wma_vec(double[:] x, double m, double[:] y) nogil:
    cdef:
        int n
        int mi = int(m)
        Py_ssize_t i, j
    n = x.shape[0]
    for i in range(mi-1, n):
        for j in range(i-mi+1, i+1):
            if j == i-mi+1:
                y[i] = x[j]
            else:
                y[i] += x[j]*float(j-i+m)
        y[i] /= float(m*(m+1))/2.0

cdef void void_vec(double[:] x, double m, double[:] y) nogil:
    pass

cdef vector_ptr stat_switch(stat_func):
    if stat_func == 'sma':
        return &sma_vec
    elif stat_func == 'wma':
        return &wma_vec
    else:
        return &void_vec

cdef double[:] stat_vec(double[:] x, double m, stat_func):
    cdef:
        vector_ptr stat_func_ptr = stat_switch(stat_func)
        double[:] y = x.copy()
    y[:] = np.nan
    stat_func_ptr(x, m, y)
    return y

cdef double[:, ::1] stat_mat(double[:, ::1] x, double m, stat_func):
    cdef:
        vector_ptr stat_func_ptr = stat_switch(stat_func)
        int n
        Py_ssize_t i
        double[:, ::1] y = x.copy()
        double[:] yi
        double[:] xi
    y[:, :] = np.nan
    n = x.shape[1]
    if n > int(m):
        for i in range(0, x.shape[0]):
            yi = y[i, :]
            xi = x[i, :]
            stat_func_ptr(xi, m, yi)
    return y

cdef ar stat_choose(ar x, double m, stat_func):
    if x.ndim == 1:
        return np.asarray(stat_vec(x, m, stat_func))
    elif x.ndim == 2:
        return np.asarray(stat_mat(x, m, stat_func))
    else:
        raise ValueError('Cannot handle more than two dimensions')

cpdef ar sma(ar x, double m):
    return stat_choose(x, m, 'sma')

cpdef ar wma(ar x, double m):
    return stat_choose(x, m, 'wma')
```

Description of the code above:

1. functions `sma_vec`, `wma_vec`, calculate some metrics over `x` and return the output in `y` (in this example, a rolling moving average and a rolling weighted moving average).
2. function `stat_switch` switches to either `sma_vec` or `wma_vec` depending upon the value of `stat_func` and `void_vec` is a dummy function that does nothing.
3. function `stat_vec` returns the output of `sma_vec` or `wma_vec` over a 1-Dimensional vector
4. function `stat_mat` returns the output of `sma_vec` or `wma_vec` by looping over the rows of a 2-Dimensional vector (C-type rows)
5. function `stat_choose` checks if it is 1-Dimensional `np.ndarray` or 2-Dimensional `np.ndarray` and accordingly redirects the result to either `stat_vec` or `stat_mat`
6. functions `sma` and `wma` are intended to be python wrappers for `stat_choose`.

The setup file is as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy as np

ext_modules = [Extension('movavg1', ['stat/movavg1.pyx'], include_dirs=[np.get_include()],
                         define_macros=[('NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API', None)],
                         extra_compile_args=['-O3', '-march=native', '-ffast-math']
                         )]

setup(
    name="Moving Average Functions",
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules=ext_modules
)
```

To parallelize the `stat_mat` function, where I have a loop, I do the following:

1. At the top, I added:

`from cython.parallel import prange`

2. Changed the `stat_mat` code to (changed `range` to `prange`):

   instead of `range(0, x.shape[0])`, I am using `prange(x.shape[0], nogil=True)`
3. In the setup file, I added `-fopenmp` to the `ext_modules`:

   `extra_compile_args=['-O3', '-march=native', '-ffast-math', '-fopenmp'],`

   `extra_link_args=['-fopenmp']`

When I try to compile this, I get an error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    n = x.shape[1]
    if n > int(m):
        for i in prange(x.shape[0], nogil=True):
            yi = y[i, :]
            xi = x[i, :]
            stat_func_ptr(xi, m, yi)
                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

stat\movavg1.pyx:73:25: Calling gil-requiring function not allowed
without gil
```

How can I convert this code to compile it such that the `stat_mat` is parallelized?

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
ctypedef void (*vector_ptr)(double[:], double, double[:])
```

To

```
ctypedef void (*vector_ptr)(double[:], double, double[:]) nogil
```

Unfortenly I wont be able to test this until tomorrow.

Comment: My apologies I changed my answer. What you are doing looks correct to me. I will be able to try a couple of test tomorrow. But I have changed my answer in the mean time to one very simple solution you might like to try (but I Cannot check to see that it works).

Answer (score 0):

```
ctypedef void (*vector_ptr)(double[:], double, double[:]) nogil
```

For Baum mit Augen: the nogil qualifier must be a part of the function pointer type when using function pointer to nogil functions. Only nogil functions can be called in a prange block. But when the function pointer type did not contain the nogil qualifier it is illegal to call inside a orange or nogil block.

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with OP's code and why this solves the problem *by editing you answer*.